# Use dynamically type of generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

```
export const createBill = /* GraphQL */ `mutation CreateBill(
  $input: CreateBillInput!
  $condition: ModelBillConditionInput
) {
  createBill(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
    periodStart
    periodEnd
    energy
    senderId
    receiverId
    metering_point_number
    file_key
    customer_number
    bill_number
    paid
    interval
    id
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    __typename
  }
}
` as GeneratedMutation<
  APITypes.CreateBillMutationVariables,
  APITypes.CreateBillMutation
>;
```

I have this graphql query which is automatically generated.

Now I try to create an function that takes in the string `createBill` and variables. The variables are the `CreateBillMutationVariables` and the return type should be `CreateBillMutation`

How do I do this?

```
import * as mutations from '@/src/graphql/mutations'

export const apiQuery = <
  T extends keyof typeof mutations,
  F extends (typeof mutations)[T]
>(
  query: T,
  variables: F
) => {
  return API.graphql(graphqlOperation(query, variables))
}
```

I have tried this, it works for query, but not for variables.

[image]

EDIT:
[image]

```
import * as mutations from '@/src/graphql/mutations'

export const apiQuery = <
  T extends keyof typeof mutations,
  F extends (typeof mutations)[T]['__generatedMutationInput']
>(
  query: T,
  variables: F
) => {
  return API.graphql(graphqlOperation(query, variables))
}

apiQuery('createBill', {input:{}})
```

This looks much better now, but the problem here is that my variables now accepts `input` and then the actual variables, how do I type it that it only accepts the variables.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that we can use to see the issue for ourselves in our own IDEs.  Right now there are a lot of external types and variables that prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, you should alter your function signature like this:

```js
export const apiQuery = <
  T extends keyof typeof mutations,
  F extends (typeof mutations)[T]['__generatedMutationInput']['input']
>(
  query: T,
  variables: F
)
```

Though I have my doubt on using `__generatedMutationInput`, there might be cleaner solutions.